# club members "at the school" or "of the school"?

Tags: prepositional-phrases

Is there any difference between following sentences:

1. Cooking club members at the High School work at a restaurant in New Jersey on Saturdays and Sundays.
2. Cooking club members of the High School work at a restaurant in New Jersey on Saturdays and Sundays.

Which one do native speakers normally use?

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is more correct, but still ambiguous. A better sentence would be:

> Members of the High School Cooking Club work at a restaurant ...

The second sentence is incorrect, because it reads like the people in question are members of the high school, not the cooking club, and then the sentence doesn't scan.

Comment: In order to clarify the problem, if I replace "Cooking club members" with "Staffs", are both those prepositions at/of correct? - again. thanks in advance.

Comment: Staffs would be wrong. 'Staff' would be appropriate if the members of the cooking club are staff.